# Social sharing buttons invalidate XHTML

Tags: xhtml, social-networking, validation

I've written valid `XHTML 1.0 Transitional` Code. I want to add social sharing buttons (twitter, facebook and google+), but all of these buttons invalidate my code. Is there any solution available?

Comment: Share some of the examples you had and HOW they break the code.

Answer (score 3):

Many articles on this topic of whether valid html is important. The majority say it isn't and I'm going to completely disagree with them. I have brought sites up to front pages of google just by validating the code and trying (as much as possible) to have the indentation formated. But as I say more disagree with me than agree.

So when I used the social media buttons I found one that will validate. I used the "share this" system and deleted the 'displayText' attribute for each span. This means that the alt text (tooltip) when you hover the icon won't show. But if someone has an account with that social media then they will prob recognise the icon anyways.
http://sharethis.com/

So the code that they say to use is:

```
    <span class='st_stumbleupon_large' displayText='StumbleUpon'></span>
    <span class='st_digg_large' displayText='Digg'></span>
    <span class='st_pinterest_large' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
    <span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
    <span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
    <span class='st_sharethis_large' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
    <span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
```

and i changed it to:

```
    <span class='st_stumbleupon_large'></span>
    <span class='st_digg_large'></span>
    <span class='st_pinterest_large'></span>
    <span class='st_facebook_large'></span>
    <span class='st_twitter_large'></span>
    <span class='st_sharethis_large'></span>
    <span class='st_email_large'></span>
```

and now validates to xHTML (should work for html5) as well.

Answer (score -1):

Validity are not rules, but are guidelines. Keeping things valid or not valid does not actually make that huge of a difference.

If they work, and your break appears correct in browsers then it should not be an issue to you if it validates or not.

Comment: gonna disagree here. In my experience - and this is a debatable topic - having xhtml code that validates in http://validate.w3c.org and even having as close as possible indent formated xhtml has always improved search rankings. But there are many that disagree and this is just based on my experience